# Mysql table join 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have two tables in mySQL:

Table 1:
Club(ClubID=PK, club_name)

Table 2:
League_table(tableID=PK, position, clubID=fk, games_played, points)

how would i join the two tables to give a query that displayed only

(position, club-name, games_played)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_join#Left_outer_join ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple join:

```
select l.position, c.club_name, l.games_played
from club c, league_table l 
where l.clubid=c.clubid
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a left join. ClubID is the foreign key (the column "connecting"  the two tables).

```
select position, club_name, games_played
from league_table
left join club on club.ClubId = league_table.clubID
```

Answer (score 0):

**select a.club_name, b.position, b.games_played
from club as a join league_table as b
on a.clubid=b.clubid**
Thats what you want.

**@Alexen:** No need of left join in this case.

**@Diegoe:** one friendly advise, always use on in join, without it query goes slow down when you are working on big tables.